# Detecting a mouse click in python, without extensive checking via loops

Tags: python, events, mouseevent

EDIT: I FOUND A SOLUTION, DONT BOTHER ANSWERING

I want my program to run in the background and execute a block of code once I click in a specified area of my monitor. I could do this by running a loop that checks whether the mouse has been clicked and if it was in the area, but I'm afraid my inputs will get eaten between updates.
So I want the program to essentially pause and only run once the mouse has been clicked.

I tried the mouse.on_click() function of the mouse library, but when run in a testing environment, my program would just run the code whether I clicked or not, then finishing the run before I even got to click. Code looks like this:

```
import mouse

def check_for_game(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    mouse.on_click(check_hitbox(x1, y1, x2, y2))


def check_hitbox(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    if x1 <= mouse.get_position()[0] <= x2 and y1 >=   mouse.get_position()[1] >= y2:
        print("click in box detected")

check_for_game(0, 1000, 1000, 0)
```

I'm not familiar with event based programming at all, sadly, so I'm a bit lost trying to figure this out, I've seen people use the mouse.hook() function, but that got me even more confused. The internet has not been useful as well...

Edit:
I found a solution for this problem using pynput's mouse Listener online. For anyone with a similar problem, here's the working code:

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed and str(button) == "Button.left":
        print(f"left button at {x}, {y}")
    

with mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

This code will print the coordinates of the mouse to the console only if the left mouse button was clicked.

Comment: the code needs to be checking for an event.  currently it just has 2 function which are never called.

Comment: Turtle has an onclick function.